# MS-Access 2010: Mouse events "dead" in main form

Tags: ms-access, mouseevent, eventtrigger, subform

MS-Access 2010:
Main form with item names and subform with item actions (date of action, etc.).
Purpose = quick consulting data using only the mouse, without any editing.

Idea: to switch to subform and back to mainform just by moving the mouse.

This works perfectly from the mainform to the subform (code in subform):

```
Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Forms![MyMainForm]![MySubForm].SetFocus
End Sub
```

I tried to use the analogous procedure for back from the subform to the mainform. However, once the mouse has been over the subform, moving the mouse over the mainform or over a mainform's field, or even clicking on the mainform's background does not trigger the desired mouse actions (checked by inserting Stop into the corresponding code). By the way, clicking on the mainform's background with focus on the mainform triggers the mouse action, but .SetFocus leads to an error (no allowed action there).

Hence, the only way to set the focus back to the main form seems to be clicking into a field on the main form. But this is not self-evident for the users.

Comment: You can't set the focus on a form. What you are doing with `Forms![MyMainForm]![MySubForm].SetFocus` is setting the focus on the subform control. You need to set focus to a control on the main form.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed was to set the focus on the main form by moving the mouse. Of course, FIRST the focus MUST be set onto the main form, only thereafter one can focus on any field on the main form. The problem was that neither the main form itself nor its background do trigger mouse actions able to perform the action .SetFocus once the focus is on the subform.

However, I designed a work-around which works: over the whole form width at the bottom of the main form, I created a large, transparent, unbound Dummy field, which the mouse automatically crosses when it leaves the subform. Following code is in the main form's module:

```
Private Sub Dummy_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Me.SetFocus
Me![Empty].SetFocus
End Sub
```

Empty is a very small unbound field in a corner, to which the focus is set in a second step, where the cursor blinks to indicate the main form has focus.

It works ! Just the Dummy field must be big enough otherwise the mouse's crossing time is too short to trigger the desired action; this limitates the possibilities of design for the main form.